# Getting a record in an azure table that contains a sequence of words using LINQ in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq, azure

I have an Azure table that has a column named "`PartitionKey`".

The following code gets as input a keyword and returns the records that have the same "`PartitionKey`" as the keyword. For example if the keyword is "Massachusetts Institute of Technology" and the table has a record with PartitionKey "Massachusetts Institute of Technology" I get that record.

I need something different than that. If the PartitionKey is "Massachusetts Institute of Technology" and the Keyword is "Institute of Technology" to get that record as well. That is I want that to happen if the keyword is a word or a sequence of words. However, if for example the keyword is "Massachu", the code has to return 0 results while if the keyword is "Massachusetts" to get the whole record for "Massachusetts Institute of Technology". Is it that possible?

```
TableQuery<Entity> query=
new TableQuery<Entity>()
.Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey",
QueryComparisons.Equal, keyword));
```

Answer (score -1):

Not in front of something I can test this on, but maybe this:

```
var query = new TableQuery<Entity>().Where(t => t.PartitionKey.CompareTo(keyword)>=0);
```

If I recall correctly, TableQuery's are somewhat limited in this respect.

**Edit:** Seems a bit of clarity is in order. Since OData doesn't support string functions, one is usually stuck with starts with/ends with type functionality. This topic is treated more in depth [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796231.aspx), but the most immediately relevant bit of it seems to be this:

```
var query = _serviceContext.FoodTable.AsTableServiceQuery()
        .Where(c => c.PartitionKey.CompareTo("Vegetable")>=0
        && c.PartitionKey.CompareTo("Vegetablf")<0
        && c.Color == "Green");
```

In the above code, PartionKeys such as "Vegetable" and "Vegetablef" would be fine, but "VegetableLike" or "VegetableSomethingElse" would be right out. The predicates established the lower and upper bounds of query.

Given the limitations, I fear what the OP wants to accomplish (full text whole word search, if understand correctly) isn't wholly realizable via the TableQuery object.

Comment: But how can this solve OP's problem? What happens in the case that there is a record with "PartitionKey" "Massachusetts Institute of Technology" and the keyword is "Massachusetts"? The code should return that record as well. Does this happen in the code you provided?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Jim. I provided more detail. I hope it sufficiently clarifies the answer.

Comment: hmm... Thanks. What is the type of _serviceContext and how is it initialised?

Comment: While not shown in the article linked, it seems to be a private field and likely derived from TableServiceContext. If one is going to work with the Table Storage API one requires such a class to facilitate queries and the like.